# How to find out names and numbers of users on your system?

Tags: debian, command-line, system-information

One way to find the names is to look at /home/ and see whichever entries are on the system.

To look at current users one can use

```
#users
```

to see how many users are there.

If a single user has spawned many sessions you will get something like -

```
root@debian:~# users
shirish shirish shirish shirish shirish shirish shirish
```

Is there any other way to know about users on the system other than the two shared above ?

Comment: last, who, ps are all relevant.

Comment: didn't know about last and who. Last is much better, thanx. I think you can put it in an answer and I would reward you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways.  `last`, `who` and `ps` are all relevant here.  `last` is the most thorough for tracking current *and past* logins.

From the man page for `last` (emphasis added):

> Last will list the sessions of specified users, ttys, and hosts, in
>        reverse time order.  Each line of output contains the user name, the tty
>        from which the session was conducted, any hostname, the start and stop
>        times for the session, and the duration of the session.  **If the session
>        is still continuing or was cut short by a crash or shutdown, last will so
>        indicate.**
>
> ...
>
> If no users, hostnames or terminals are
>        specified, last prints a record of all logins and logouts.

So rather than only reporting on the sessions currently in progress, `last` reports on *all* logins and logouts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `who` . To  list users logged in :

```
who -u
```

To count all login names and number of users logged on:

```
who -q
```

Or using `wc` command:

```
users | wc -w
```